# Regex validation of two patterns multiple comma-separated doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

In an ASP.NET form I am trying to find a pattern allowing multiple comma-separated elements but it doesn't seem to work. I need to allow either 4 letters and 2 digits (JEAN01) or 2 digits and 4 letters (01JEAN) any number of times: `JEAN01,JEAN02,03JEAN,JEAN04`

My first attempt (see https://regex101.com/r/E4JZVv/1) is:

```
/^([a-z-A-Z]{4}[0-9]{2}|[a-z-A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4})(,[a-z-A-Z]{4}[0-9]{2}|[a-z-A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4})*$
```

My second attempt (https://regex101.com/r/HU9cOS/1) is

```
((^|[,])[a-z-A-Z]{4}[0-9]{2}|[a-z-A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4})+
```

The first accepts only a couple of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
^((\w{4}\d{2}|\d{2}\w{4})(,|$))+
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/8hoNXl/1

---

**Explanation:**

- `^`: Asserts position at start of the string
- `\w{4}\d{2}`: 4 letters and 2 digits
- `\d{2}\w{4}`: 2 digits and 4 letters
- `(,|$)`: Either `,` or the end of the string
- `+`: Repeat between once and an unlimited number of times (greedy)

Comment: Wouldn't it stop at the first element that doesn't match, even if there might be other candidates after?

Comment: @Jimi Since it validates a pattern, either the entire string matches or nothing matches.

Comment: Possible. I saw the *second attempt* and it looks like the OP is trying to get the elements that match the criteria, discard the rest. Not actually sure what is the expected result.

Comment: In his first try he used ``^`` and ``$``... Must admit it's quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The setup of your first try is good, only:

- you want to match `4 letters and 2 digits or 2 digits and 4 letters` which is different from  this part `[a-z-A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}`
- In the repetition of the group in the second part, you have to repeat the comma and put that following alternation itself also in a group so that the comma can be prepended for both alternations

Using a case insensitive match:

```
(?i)^(?:[a-z]{4}[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{2}[a-z]{4})(?:,(?:[a-z]{4}[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{2}[a-z]{4}))*$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2oCdNC/1).

For the second pattern that you tried, the assertion for the start of the string should not be in an alternation, or else you can have partial matches as it will also allow a comma.

You can repeat the alternation with an optional comma at the end. If you don't want to allow the string to start with a comma, you can for example using a negative lookahead `(?!,)` and  use the alternation after asserting the start of the string.

```
(?i)^(?!,)((?:,|^)(?:[a-z]{4}[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{2}[a-z]{4}))+$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VqdCiR/1).